# Getting memory location of C++ static variable in Visual Studio Community Debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, memory, static

In this simple C++ program:

```cpp
int main() {
    int n = 0xffffff12;
    static int q = 0x7fffffff;
    static int r = 0x10000000;
    static int R = 0x80000000;
    return 0;
}
```

I can retrieve the actual memory location of variable `n` in Visual Studio Community debugger by looking at the assembly instruction in disassembly, getting the offset from that instruction, and adding it to the base pointer (`EBP`).

But since static variables are allocated on program startup, how would I get their memory locations in the Visual Studio Debugger?

[image: visual studio community debugger windows]

Comment: First, why would you want to know the locations of statics even if they existed? A static int will be a direct assignment in the running code, not in a conventional memory location.

Comment: But to answer your question, you will not find it in the debugger. You can see it if you look at the disassembly.

Comment: It is only for academic/learning purposes to try and demonstrate that static variables are allocated memory on program startup

Comment: They are not allocated. They are hard coded. There is no other mechanism than an op code sets a register with a value.

Comment: @lakeweb is correct, unless you create a pointer to one of those static variables there won't be any memory allocated for them. Otherwise it's not too different from a `#define`.

Comment: Ah I see - only after I put a line such as `q = r + R;` was I able to see them in memory. Thanks!